# How can I downgrade my HTC Explorer from Android 4.0 to 2.3

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, 2.3-gingerbread, downgrade, htc-explorer

Android 4.0 is installed on my HTC Explorer, but now I want to install again the previous version which was 2.3 Gingerbread.

Could anyone please tell me how to do that?

Comment: Why do you want to downgrade? Just curiosity...

Comment: Because, its doesn't work very well.

Answer (score 0):

One option is using RUUs. A few Google searches should get you going.

Another is flashable stock ROM zips. A few searches in the XDA Developers forum for that device should put you in track.